# HLS live steaming using Android videoview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I am developing Xamarin application for android and iOS. I am trying to playing live stream HLS URL using Videoview and Media controller controls for Android version.

I am able to run below url:
https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8

But I am not able to play the HLS live stream url given by client. Am I missing something? or I have to find new Code or package.

Code for playing video:

```
private void InitVideoView()
   {
      _videoView = new VideoView(Context);
      _videoView.Holder.SetKeepScreenOn(true);
      _videoView.Prepared += videoView_Prepared;
      _videoView.Error += videoView_Error;
      _videoView.Completion += videoView_Completion;
      _videoView.Info += videoView_Info;
      _videoView.SetOnPreparedListener(this);

      var lv = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
      lv.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterInParent);
      _videoView.LayoutParameters = lv;
      Control.AddView(_videoView);
      //Org.Apache.Http.Conn.Ssl.SSLSocketFactory.AllowAllHostnameVerifier
   }


    public void OnPrepared(Android.Media.MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer)
   {
        //Console.WriteLine($"OnPrepared: {Status}");
        _mediaPlayer.SetVolume(0f, 0f);
        _videoView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        _prepared = true;
       Play();
   }

   private void InitMediaController()
   {
        mediaController = new MyMediaController(Context, false);
        mediaController.VisibilityChange += MediaController_VisibilityChange;

        mediaController.SetAnchorView(_videoView);
        //_videoView.SetMediaController(mediaController);
        _videoView.SetMediaController(null);
   }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? What are the HLS live stream specs that you are trying to receive/display?  Monitor logcat for media specific errors/warnings.

Comment: it is live stream of camera. It gives me below error:
03-01 15:44:43.047 V/MediaPlayerNative(32728): back from callback
03-01 15:44:43.047 V/MediaPlayerNative(32728): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1007
03-01 15:44:43.047 E/MediaPlayerNative(32728): error (1, -1007)
03-01 15:44:43.047 V/MediaPlayerNative(32728): callback application
03-01 15:44:43.047 V/MediaPlayerNative(32728): back from callback
03-01 15:44:43.048 E/MediaPlayer(32728): Error (1,-1007)
03-01 15:44:43.048 D/VideoView(32728): Error: 1,-1007
03-01 15:44:43.079 I/MediaHTTPConnection(32728): response code = 200

Comment: sounds like it is an RTSP stream(?), open your stream in VLC and look at the stream info.